# Foreign Key constraint may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api

I'm getting the following error `Foreign Key constraint may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths` with my migrations in my .NET CORE project. I have these 3 identites:

```
public class Post
{
        [Key]
        public long Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public long UserID { get; set; }
        public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

        ...
}

public class Album
{
        [Key]
        public long Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public long UserID { get; set; }
        public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

        ...
}

public class PostAlbum
{
        public long PostID { get; set; }
        public virtual Post Post { get; set; }

        public long AlbumID { get; set; }
        public virtual Album Album { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using the fluent api to map the Foreign key of the entity PostAlbum:

```
builder.Entity<PostAlbum>(x =>
{
                x.HasKey(y => new { y.PostID, y.AlbumID });
                x.HasOne(y => y.Post).WithMany().HasForeignKey("PostID").OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
                x.HasOne(y => y.Album).WithMany().HasForeignKey("AlbumID").OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
});
```

The logic: A Post could be storaged in many albums and an album could has many posts.

The problem is that, if I change the DeleteBehavior to DeleteBehavior.Restrict, I can't delete a Post entity because it gets into conflict with the Foreign key of PostAlbum.

Error:

[image]

Someone could help me?

Comment: This model shouldn't be a problem. Didn't you leave out other relationships?

Comment: @GertArnold the Post and Album have a relationship with the ApNetUsers by the property public long UserID { get; set; } . I have updated the models on the question.

Comment: This causes a cycle User-Album-PostAlbum-Post-User. You have to remove the cascaded delete from one of the FKs in this cycle.

Comment: @GertArnold when I use x.HasOne(y => y.Post).WithMany().HasForeignKey("PostID").OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade) the cascade is applied when the Post is deleted, the PostAlbum is also deleted or when a PostAlbum is deleated, the Post is also deleted?

Comment: No, only deletion of Posts deletes PostAlbums. But SQL Server doesn't want to decide whether Post or Album should be responsible for deleting PostAlbums when deleting a User. The cycle could easily be resolved if SQL Server would take the effort, Unfortunately, it doesn't (I didn't invent it...).

Comment: @GertArnold but if I remove the Cascade from PostAlbum.AlbumID for exeample, if I delete the album, the PostAlbum will still exist and It's not right, does It?

Comment: Well, you couldn't even delete the Album because of FK violation. I think you have to remove the cascaded delete from one of the UserIDs.